# Multiple Joins in a Single SQL Command

Tags: join

I am working with the R programming language. I am trying to perform an INNER JOIN if Condition 1 OR Condition 2 is met:

**Condition_1**

if table_1$id = table_2$id AND

if table_1$date BETWEEN(table_2$date_2,table_2$date_3)

**Condition_2**

if table_1$id2 = table_2$id2

**Question:** I tried to use the code below to achieve the above task:

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select distinct * 
  from table_1 a inner join table_2 b
  on (a.date_1 between b.date_2 and b.date_3) and 
     a.id = b.id or (a.id2 = b.id2)")
```

The above code successfully ran, but I am not sure if the logic is correct.

Can someone please tell me if what I have done is correct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note you should always tag which database system and version you're using as well.*

It seems that your query is almost correct, except you have your parenthesis in the wrong place. Rather you should put parenthesis around your two sets of criteria in the `AND` condition like so:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM table_1 a INNER JOIN table_2 b
    ON ((a.date_1 BETWEEN b.date_2 AND b.date_3) AND 
    a.id = b.id) or a.id2 = b.id2
```

Also, seeing as you were wondering about performance in your last question, you may be interested in knowing that using an `OR` condition in a `WHERE` clause can *sometimes* hinder performance by making it difficult for the query optimize in being able to choose the most efficient index operation and plan. An alternative way to (usually) rewrite a query that uses an `OR` condition in a *potentially more efficient* manner is by using the `UNION` clause instead. Here's an example demonstrating that with your query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM table_1 a INNER JOIN table_2 b
    ON (a.date_1 BETWEEN b.date_2 AND b.date_3) AND 
    a.id = b.id

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM table_1 a INNER JOIN table_2 b
    ON a.id2 = b.id2
```

Note I mentioned this was *potentially more efficient* as with performance tuning, testing between two queries is always necessary to determine the true best implementation for a specific use case, and your mileage may vary.

Comment: @ J.D. Thank you so much for your answer! I tried to look for "R SQL", but unfortunately  no such tag existed.

Comment: I am not sure if you are familiar with the "dplyr" library in R - but would this also work? table_1 %>%

inner_join(table_2, by= "id") %>%

filter(date_1 > date_2, date_1 < date_3) %>%

left_join(table_2, by= "id2") %>%

mutate_all(as.factor)

Comment: @stats555 No problem! Moreso by my note I meant you should tag if the database you're querying is Microsoft SQL Server, Oracle PL/SQL, PostgreSQL, MySQL, etc. I'm guessing you're using a Microsoft SQL Server database, based on your syntax and the fact you're using R, but I'm not positive. I am not familiar with the syntax of the R language itself, sorry. That's possibly a better fit question for StackOverflow. But you can see my updated answer which offers a second way you can rewrite your original query, in a potentially more efficient manner too.